Some third party sources weren't added back after 24.04 upgrade
So, I recently upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04. This wasn't a issue in other minor upgrade, but it seems that my third party repos for vscode weren't turned added back to sources after the upgrade was complete. Running sudo apt update doesn't list any other repo than ubuntu's. I had third party repos for chrome and vscode. While chrome seems to be easy to activate from "software & Updates" app(there's just a checkmark), vscode doesn't seem to have one. On closer inspection, running ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d returns
google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
google-chrome.list.save
google-chrome.sources
ubuntu.sources
vscode.list.distUpgrade
vscode.list.save

Should I add vscode's repo back using the official instructions? Since this wasn't the case for previous release I am not sure if its required...

the upgrade process never does. You need to add them.

"this wasn't the case for previous release" A correctly-done release-upgrade has always disabled non-Ubuntu sources, as those sources are a major source of breakage. It's up to you, the human, to determine if 1) Using a non-Ubuntu source is still appropriate for your needs, and 2) Whether to simply re-enable (and perhaps update) the old source or to re-add the source anew.

It is correct that the third party sources were disabled, this has been case in every release, but this time a repository wasn't just disabled, it wasn't even added back(in disabled state) in the list. I needed clarification on weather ubuntu didn't add it because of a reason or it was just a fluke?

@user535733 in my impression earlier releases simply comment out the 3rd-party sources.

@Ziyuan "comment out" = "disabled".
